# Import UTF-8, other format flat files (text, tab delimited) into SQL Server

Tags: sql, encoding, sql-server-2014

I'm using SQL Server 2014 Enterprise edition. I'm trying to import UTF-8 and other formatted text files. I have many files that have been exported from a forensic tools and provided to us in UTF-8, TCA Taiwan, and Chinese (Big5) formats. When I map the files, SQL Server considers them ANSI (i.e., when I do a "suggest types" in the Advanced tab, SQL Server proposes `varchar` data types, even though the code page on the first tab is 65001 (UTF-8)).

Does this mean the file will be imported as UTF-8, but into a `varchar` column? Or will I lose my foreign characters? Or is the data in fact ANSI, even though the encoding shows UTF-8 in the import wizard? A mixture of both? If I change the data types to `nvarchar`, then I get 65001 vs 1252 coding issues, etc. as SQL Server can't process any of this.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are the text files delimited (e.g., CSV) or fixed-format?  Do you know the encoding of each of the files, or does each file need to be tested against possible alternatives?  If the file are delimited and the encoding know, you could try using the IMPORT metacommand of execsql.py: http://execsql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/metacommands.html#import -- I wrote it specifically to work around the limitations of the SSMS import wizard.

Comment: Yes, these files are TSV (tab separated text files).  Typically I would know the encoding up front as they are presented in batches in one encoding or another.  Thanks for the response and link.